# I keep getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters with Eclipse, but Junit5 installed

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

Hello I am writing some Junit5 test cases, but I get the following error message when I execute the Junit5 test case...

```
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Yet I do not know why because:

1. Clicking on the /src folder and selecting “configure build path”, and selecting the libraries tab, under the module path it indicates that it has “Junit 5” added to the libraries JARS and class folders on the build path.
2. The “pom.xml” contains the following:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>au.edu.rmit.ct</groupId>
  <artifactId>DietelATMCaseStudyUpgrade</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

3. Selecting the test file to execute, selecting from the context menu, “Run As”.. “Run Configurations it shows the test runner on the Test tab as Junit5, an on the Dependencies tab.. And on the module past entries  it is showing Junit 5.

Clearly there is a misconfiguration somewhere, but I am not able to identify where, does any-one have a suggestion? (I am running Eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0) )

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dependency.  Specifically a class which does not exist in your existing dependencies.

You can tell by looking at the source code of the dependency directly:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.7.2/

If you unzip that, you will see that the package org/junit/platform does not exist and nor is that class, therefore add the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response and with this I have:
1. Added the dependency as you indicated to my POM.xml file
2. Clicked on the project and checked the Build Path libraries and it has the JRE System Library (JavaSE-1.8); J unit 5.
3. I do not have a .classpath file in my project root
4. I am not familiar with maven, but if I installed that function in my eclipse, Would it help resolve and manage my dependencies?
5. I then re-ran it, as a Junit, and I still get the same error message..
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters

Comment: If you have pom.xml then you are using maven.   Go to your directory where pom.xml is located, and write mvn clean install    on your command line, and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for the help, as I found the problem was that I had to edit my .classpath file, and when I did that, It worked. I will need to understand maven better, and once this current testing is done I will investigate that.